# "enum" and "#define" in C language

Tags: c

I have a few line of code, if I write "#define"s above of the "enum"s (same as below code) compiler giving error like that :

```
#define TEAMA 0         //  This throw
#define TEAMB 1         //  ERROR
#define TEAMC 2 

enum Teams {
    TEAMA,
    TEAMB,
    TEAMC 
  };
```

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
#define TEAMA 0   
              ^
```

if I write "#define"s below of the "enum"s, I don't getting any error.

What is the logic behind of this situation?

Comment: Macros are pure text-replacement, so what you are doing is telling the compiler to replace each occurence of `TEAMA` with the number 0. An `enum Teams { 0, 1, 2 }` is obviously not valid syntax

Comment: Do you mean `enum Teams { TEAMA = 0, ... }`? Since `0` is the default for the first entry, this is kind of redundant unless you anticipate adding and removing values which could confuse the integer equivalents.

Comment: Compilers have flag to stop after pre-processing stage (`gcc -E`) to help to understand.

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires `enum` constants and macros with the same name?

Answer (score 7):

When you do a define the compiler will do a text substitution when it encounters one of the defined symbols

so

```
#define TEAMA 0         //  This throw
#define TEAMB 1         //  ERROR
#define TEAMC 2 

enum Teams {
    TEAMA,
    TEAMB,
    TEAMC 
  };
```

becomes

```
   enum Teams {
       0,
       1,
       2
   };
```

which obviously is wrong

Instead don't have those defines and use the enum directly since it defines those symbols, but then as enum members.

```
// TEAMA will have by default value 0, TEAMB 1, TEAMC 2
enum Teams { TEAMA,TEAMB,TEAMC }; 

if ( TEAMA == 0 ) puts( "TEAMA!");
```

Comment: That condition is a tautology...

Answer (score 1):

Macro definitions are simply textual replacements (more precisely tokens). It is done by the preprocessor before compiling the C code.

So in your example, the compiler will compile:

```
enum Teams {
    0,
    1,
    2
  };
```

which is obviously not the correct C code.

https://godbolt.org/z/dYEfMoaYf

Answer (score 1):

Apart of the answers you have received, you need to understand one difference between using the **macros** defined to hold the constants, and the enum type in C.

Besides the type becoming an integer and so, be equivalently treated by all functions (which gives no special security, as it does an enum in many other languages) the symbol specified by a macro definition is expanded at preprocessing input, and finally ends being substituted in every place where the macro is called, but no symbol finally is known to the C compiler itself.

In the case it becomes a language symbol, the compiler can generate proper debugging info an will allow you to see the full symbol name, when a value of that enumeration type is shown in the debugger.  For this reason, the enumeration should be preferred in new code (and probably be refactored in old, legacy code)

The macro way was the only way in old, pre 1st ed. K&R C language.  (in K&R 1st edition of "The C programming language" already appears the possibility of enumeration definition)